# Why isn't the coefficient for the linear model showing up the same on the plot? in R

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I am stumped by R. And this might not be the best forum for this type of question, so apologies if I should post this elsewhere.

I have a linear regression through some data that looks like this:

[image]

But when I call on the coefficients of the linear model, it reads:

```
> fit$coefficients
(Intercept)   data$logA 
3.1370219   0.1718147
```

And obviously the y-intercept is more like 2 and not 3. How can this be?!

Here's my code:

```
data <- read.csv("Diamond1976_Table1.csv",header=T,sep=",") # read the csv file 
# Make the first species-area curve
Area <- data$A_mi2
Slow <- data$S_low
plot(Area, Slow, xlab = "Area (mi^2)",
     ylab = "Species Richness",
     pch = 15, cex = 1, col = "skyblue")

# Take the logarithm of the data
data$logS_low = log(data$S_low)
data$logS_mt = log(data$S_mt)
data$logA = log(data$A_mi2)

# Log plot
plot(data$logA, data$logS_low, xlab = "Log area",
     ylab = "Log species richness", main = "Log-log plot Diamond (1976)",
     pch = 15, cex = 1, col = "skyblue")
fit <- lm(data$logS_low ~ data$logA) # tilda is "explained by"
abline(fit)
summary(fit)
fit$coefficients
```

Can anyone find an obvious mistake? I can post the data if that's helpful but I feel like someone can explain why this is happening without the data.

Comment: Intercept is value on y-axis when value on x-axis is 0

Comment: So calling something like ``fit[y="0?]` should get me the y-intercept?

Comment: To predict y values from `fit` for any x value: `predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(logA=0))`. `logA=0` will give you the y-intercept. Instead of `logA=0`, you can enter a vector of any x-values you want, e.g., `predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(logA=seq(-6,6,length.out=100)))`

Comment: @eip10 I get the error: `Warning message:
'newdata' had 100 rows but variables found have 50 rows`

Comment: I think that you are misreading the graph.  You said "obviously the y-intercept is more like 2 and not 3".  The height is 2 at the far left, but that is not at x=0, rather, it is at about x = 6.2.  The slope displayed looks about right if you account for the fact that the scales on the x and y axes are not the same.

Comment: When you fit the model, change your code to: `fit <- lm(logS_low ~ logA, data=data)`. If you fit the model by including the data frame name for each variable, then `predict` looks for the exact same name in the new data, rather than just the column name.

Comment: duh. thanks @G5W. That explains it!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you just misread the plot -- the intercept is where the line crosses x=0:

[image: plot of data with a line drawn up along actual y-axis to fitted regression line and horizontal across to the plot margin]

When doing "vanilla R" plots, I'll commonly mark in the "true" axes in grey with

```
abline(h=0,v=0,col=8)
```

If you put that just before your line `abline(fit)`, you'll get a clearer indication of the intercept.